# How to overlap 2 matrices, where zeros are "transparent"

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 matrices, say

```
A = [ 0  4  9        B = [ 0  0  2
      0  2  1              1  6  1
      3  0  0 ]            3  9  8 ]
```

I want the result to be "A overlapped with B".

- Any elements of `B` which are `0` should be "transparent" and show through the value of `A`
- All other elements should be the balue of `B`.

So I should get:

```
result = [ 0  4  2
           1  6  1
           3  9  8 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
A=[ 0   4   9;       
    0   2   1;     
    3   0   0];     

B=[ 0   0   2;
    1   6   1;
    3   9   8];


result = A;
result( B~=0 ) = B( B~=0 );
```

Comment: @DebasmitaBhoumik please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and consider upvoting and/or marking this as accepted.